# Printing from Enum Class

Tags: java, arrays, enums, enumeration

I am new to Enum type class. I have 2 Enum Class, one for Rank one for Suits as shown below

```
    public enum Rank 
{
    ACE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3),
    FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6),
    SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9),
    TEN(10), JACK(J), QUEEN(Q),
    KING(K);
    //private fields
    private final int rankValue;
//with constructor passing rankValue 
//with method getRank
}
public enum Suit 
{
    HEARTS("H"),
    SPADES("S"),
    DIAMONDS("D"),
    CLUBS("C");
    private final String suitText;
//with constructor and printSuit()
}
```

in my main method I'm figuring out how do I print them in the following:

S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9 S10 SJ SQ SK

H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9 H10 HJ HQ HK
....
followed by diamonds and clubs.

much thanks all.

Comment: Your `Rank` enum declares `JACK(J), QUEEN(Q), KING(K)` ? What are `J`, `Q` and `K`?

Comment: Iterate through `Rank`/`Suit`s `values()`.

Comment: J,Q,K are int representations of JACK QUEEN and KING

Comment: @daniu he will got `ACE, TWO`... if will iterate over `.values()` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically enum is just another java class, with some specifics, but you can mostly do the same as you can in the classic class, so for this case, eg. following:

```
public enum CardsEnumWithProps {
    HEARTS("H"),
    SPADES("S"),
    DIAMONDS("D"),
    CLUBS("C");

    private String stringSign;


    private CardsEnumWithProps(String strSign) {
        this.stringSign = strSign;  //stringSign = strSign

    }

    public String getStr() {
        return this.stringSign;
    }

}
```

Then you can call `.getStr()` on enum value like:

```
System.out.println(CardsEnumWithProps.DIAMONDS.getStr());
```

And get output `D`

For each item in enum you can iterate over `.values()` of Enum

```
 CardsEnumWithProps[] cards = CardsEnumWithProps.values();
for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
 System.out.println(cards[i].name() + " --- " + cards[i].getStr());
}
```

And you will got

```
HEARTS --- H
SPADES --- S
DIAMONDS --- D
CLUBS --- C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following code:

```
Rank [] ranks = Rank.values();
 Suit [] suits = Suit.values();
for (int i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {

for (int j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++) {

 System.out.print(suits[i].getSuitText + ranks[j].getRank()+"\s");
}

 System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. What is your code doing and why will it fix the problem?